# Delete item post closing date in SPS 2013 List

Tags: list, item

How to automatically delete the Item from the SPS 2013 List after the closing date has reached for the item. Closing date is one of the column part of the item.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement OoB Information Retention Policy where you can have the Modified Date greater than or equal to Closing Date. Item should be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can achieve this functionality using SharePoint Designer Workflow.

We have `Pause Until` option available in SPD. You can specify your **Closing date** in `Pause Until` action and then write deleting item logic.

For more detail please have a look to this [Delete list item after specific duration using SharePoint designer workflow](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/delete-list-item-after-specific-duration-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow-21074.aspx)

Let me know if this approach worked for you.

Comment: the workflow option works in SharePoint Online. Will implement the same in SharePoint 2013 OnPrem. Thanks Mate!

Comment: And please let me know whether it solved your problem.