# SharePoint 2013 Workflow to delete items based on closing date

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-server

I`ve researched a lot, but cant find option that would allow to delete an item from SPS2013 list based on the closing date reaching Today date and workflow running all the time automatically.
Imagine, data already feeded and now the execution go on based on closing date criteria.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution, created a workflow and set it run on all items every night to do the following. **Check workflow Screenshot -**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKowj.jpg

Please note: Information MGMT policy didn't ran in my case and if it would have still would have ran the workflow once, wherein the first item in the list would have been checked by workflow and not all items.

In order to run daily on all items and not just current item (usually workflow will run on one item at a time) -

**Powershell `Code`**

```
# URL of the Site 
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "example.com"

$manager = $web.Site.WorkFlowManager 

# Name of the list 
$list = $web.Lists["List name"] 

# Name of the Workflow 
$assoc = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("Workflow name","en-US") 

$data = $assoc.AssociationData 
$items = $list.Items 
foreach($item in $items) 
 { 
 $wf = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$assoc,$data,$true) 
 } 

$manager.Dispose() 
$web.Dispose()
```

Hope the solution helps others.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Information Management Policies**.

1. Go to the list's advanced settings, and change **allow mgmt of content types** to YES.
2. In list settings in the list of content types, there will only be one, called Item.  Click Item.
3. Click Information Management Policy settings.
4. check the box next to **Enable retention**
5. Then click on **Add retention stage**
6. next to **This stage is based off a date property on the item**, pick your **closing date** field
7. In Action select **Move to Recycle bin**
   [image]

This will run daily and if it is closing date it will perform the action to delete item.

Comment: @P S , no option to defina policy under information mgmt policy settings.

Comment: In information management policy check whether you have option to "Enable Retention" that will do it

Comment: I have updated my answer. no need of workflow.

Comment: This is what I have set as per my requirement. Pic link: http://imgur.com/KOKq2gT

questions:

a) will the closing date + 0 days will work?
b) will it the Information mgmt policy repeat everyday and if yes what time?

Comment: a) It should work, b)There is timer job "Information Management Policy" check its schedule, if it is weekly make it daily

Comment: @P S, I want to copy the items to archive before deleting, therefore I guess need a workflow. Also not sure how the policy will execute when there are more than one items that has the same closing date, will it execute for both items or only the first one?

Comment: Also, just to test if the information policy is working, I tried moving the item having closing date as Today to Recycle Bin and executed the Info mgmt. policy manually, still the policy didn't executed on the list. Check the screenshot for settings - 

http://imgur.com/FT5e0vS

Please let me know if anything wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40584/discussion-between-jason-and-p-s).

Comment: is this applicable for SharePoint online? i think its for on-premises only

Comment: @prasadwt, not sure. I have not tried this in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1):

I already answered similar requirement at post [Delete item post closing date in SPS 2013 List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179568/delete-item-post-closing-date-in-sps-2013-list/179570#179570).

We have `Pause Until` option available in SPD. You can specify your Closing date in Pause Until action and then write deleting item logic.

For more detail please have a look to this [Delete list item after specific duration using SharePoint designer workflow](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/delete-list-item-after-specific-duration-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow-21074.aspx)

**Another approach:**

You can create a SP Timer Job which can be scheduled for particular time duration and in Timer Job check your **closing date** and execute your logic there.

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: in my case I want the woirkflow to run all the time and it should search for field closing date when it reaches Today then should execute the workflow. I did added the pause in the past, but it trigger only when the item is edited in the SPS 2013 List. In my case once the data is feeded no modification or update will happen on the list. So wondering how the workflow would trigger to execute when the closing date is Today. Please check the workflow image for more understanding: http://imgur.com/dZgh6yG

Kindly help.

Comment: I am updating my answer with one more approach.

Comment: I m following this article to create a powershell and set it as a windows task to run it daily at midnight once.

Link: http://www.thesysadminhimself.com/2013/09/sharepoint-start-workflow-all-items-powershell.html

Please confirm if its fine.

Comment: Also, within workflow do we have an option that scans all items rather just the current item for the closing date and if it matches to Today then execute the action part of workflow.

Example: If 4 Items have closing date as Today date, then the workflow to execute for al l4 at once. (As I`ll schedule a windows task to run the workflow once in a day)

Comment: The link you provided for using powershell, I guess it will not start workflow automatically at specific time, it will start workflow when item gets created, and you want to start workflow at midnight, and as I guess you will not add an item at midnight just to get workflow started

Comment: For your requirement I guess my second approach in answer is best fit, still have a look to this link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30434.batch-updates-on-list-items-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow.aspx if you want to go for Workflow, this link contains the information regarding batch updates on list items you can try same for deleting too

Comment: From the workflow standpoint, I have created the following workflow. Picture Link: http://imgur.com/923LojN

Expectation: All the Items with closing date matches to Today today be copied to Archive List and then deleted. However the Workflow only execute for the current item and doesn't perform the check and execution for other items in the list. 

Please suggest what change in workflow that will scan the entire list and execute the workflow for all items wherein the closing date matches to Today?

Comment: Why you don't go for Loop in Workflow? refer this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/88fb5063-9d6d-48cf-b330-58f2714594f5/delete-multiple-list-items-using-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Comment: the workflow execute only if I do it manually. However if set to current list with field parameter as Closing date and Item parameters as : Closing date & Value = Today, still the workflow doesn't execute on all items that have the closing date as today. I guess, need first my workflow to execute for all items that have closing date as Today. Any suggestions?

Comment: update I was able to map a powershell to my workflow, so now the workflow executes on all items within a list at the same time. Which is good and expected. 

However, my workflow delete the items that don't have the closing date same as the system date. Wondering what change to check if the closing is system date if not don't do anything.